# Where else can I declare included scripts in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In `angular-cli.json` I have:

```
"polyfills": "polyfills.ts"
"scripts": ["script1.ts"]
```

I want to add another another polyfill script for `ie11` specifically, which I can then wrap in a conditional comment upon final build, in order to decrease load times on other browsers.

How would I go about including such a script so it compiled with the rest of the project at run time but was not going to be bundled into either of the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want cli to output the script in a separate bundle you can use [global-scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts) like:

```
"scripts": [
    { "input": "../node_modules/module-name", "output": "module-custom-name", "lazy": true}
],
```

When you specify `"lazy": true` cli will create a separate file that will contain just your module you want to load conditionally.

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you! I will look into this.

Comment: But what if i'm not working with the cli, I'm working with angular in mvc5 application (Visual Studio 2015), so how to add the polyfills

Comment: @FaresAyyad why not to use cli? Otherwise you have to include the scripts in your custom build.

Comment: How to use angular cli in vs2015, i used to build the project at all with visual studio!!? my point of view is how to add the polyfills in visual studio?

Comment: @FaresAyyad you have to research on that or create related question.