# Angular CLI include folder of scripts/styles?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm attempting to migrate from Angular 1 to 4. I was using the Yeoman Generator for the Angular 1 app but it seems Angular CLI is the way to go with Angular 2.

I'd like to import the Angular 1 app into Angular 2 and use the UpgradeModule. Is it possible, in the `angular-cli.json` file, to import a folder of JS files using wildcards? Or is there a better way to include my Angular 1 app inside the Angular 2 CLI environment?

Comment: You can still use `Yeoman` with `angular-cli`, e.g. [ngx-rocket](https://github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket)

Comment: Read the `.angular-cli.json` documentation, particularly the part about the `scripts` property. However, if you are attempting to somehow run an AngularJS app inside an Angular app, I would think twice. With regard to Yeoman, I think its time has come and gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where else can I declare included scripts in angular-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339157/where-else-can-i-declare-included-scripts-in-angular-cli)

Comment: Potentially it's a duplicate, however, all the answers I've found online are for including single scripts at a time. I have an entire Angular 1 app that needs including.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way, but I did work around the problem by using this answer to list out the files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12209020/64279