# Add js file in my angular4 application

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to use in one of my components this effect:

https://codepen.io/linrock/pen/Amdhr

my first approach was to try to translate the javascript to typescript, but then I gave up and I decided to copy the js file that you can find in the codepen and try to import it in my application.

Then, I copied the file in src/app/scripts/confetti.js and then I tried to import it in my index.html

```
<script src="scripts/confetti.js"></script>
```

But I get that the file confetti.js is not found when I run my app.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478930/how-to-import-javascript-file-into-angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where else can I declare included scripts in angular-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339157/where-else-can-i-declare-included-scripts-in-angular-cli)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to copy your js file to "src/resources/js/" and then include it in your .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "resources/js/confetti.js"
           ],
```

Comment: @incancer how can i import that to my index.html file

Comment: @SantoshrajuV you dont... i recommend you to use Angular CLI which will create the folder and file structure for you! Then you will see a ".angular-cli.json" file where you can include your js and css files.

Comment: i have included but it is showing filenot fouund error

Comment: Then it seems like ur file is not there.. make sure you are including the right files .js or .ts